# How do I handle this pointer in getaddrinfo?

Tags: c, sockets

Warning: Please treat me like the rookie I am. This is my first "real" C program. So if I don't understand some things, that's why.

I'm trying to make a chat server following the example from Beej's Guide to Network Programming. It came recommended, so there you go.

I want to have a function accept a pointer to a structure, modify properties in that pointer, and set up a listener on the passed port. In the below code, I am getting a Segmentation Fault, and I honestly can't figure out why. Blame me being green. (Developing in Netbeans 6.8 on Ubuntu, if needed):

```
#define PORT "4400"

typedef struct {
    int port;
    fd_set *connections;
    int connections_count;
    int listener;
    struct addrinfo address;
    struct addrinfo socket_hints;
} Server;

typedef struct {
    struct sockaddr_storage address;    // User's address
    int fs_id;                  // ID to the socket they belong to
    char *name;                 // Pointer to the user's name
    struct User *nextUser;      // Next user in the list
} User;

void initialize_server(Server *passed_server, char *port) {
    struct addrinfo *temp;
    int result;

    // Set up the server hints
    memset(&passed_server->socket_hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    passed_server->socket_hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    passed_server->socket_hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    passed_server->socket_hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    result = getaddrinfo(NULL, port, &passed_server->socket_hints, &temp);
    printf("Result: %d\n", result);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Set up socket stuff
    Server *server; // Set up the server
    memset(server, 0, sizeof(Server));

    fd_set read_sockets; // Master socket holder and sockets to read
    int new_connection; // Holds the socket ID of the new connection
    socklen_t address_length; // Used to hold the length of the address from the user
    struct addrinfo;

    // Useful sets
    char buffer[1024];
    int bytes_recieved;
    int yes = 1; // For SETOPT

    // Set up server info on defined port
    initialize_server(server, PORT);
    FD_ZERO(&read_sockets);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

If you need the full code (I think I posted everything essential), you can find a link below. Thanks in advance for any help or attempt at it!

<s>http://pastebin.org/529545</s>

Comment: +1, for an excellent first post. Welcome to StackOverflow. The only thing that I can think of that could improve this: If you run this code through a debugger, say gdb, with debugging info on, it should tell you what line this code is segfaulting on, which can be a good starting point for debugging.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a peek into that.

Comment: Just a few tips. You might want to trying developing on emacs 23. Also when you get a stack stump, which are normally caused by addressing invalid memory. Try using gdb and backtrace(bt). It will take you to the line that failed. And also install valgrind its very good for tracing memory errors. i.e. valgrind --leak-check=yes ./your_app. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, robUK. Why would you recommend emacs 23 over Netbeans? Is it just preference like the vim/emacs debate? From what I can tell, I already am using gbd, but since I've never used a debugger like this I'm still getting used to it. I'll look into backtrace and valgrind. I've heard of them, just not what they do.

Comment: @Codeacula - you could also try `ddd`, which provides a GUI front end to gdb and is somewhat easier to use.

Comment: I got gbd to work in Netbeans well enough with some configuration. I'm learning what debugging it like along with my mistakes, so it took a bit of orientation. I'll look into that also. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line:

```
Server *server;
```

does not actually allocate any space for a server structure, just for a pointer to one, that's set to a random value.

It looks like the change you need is:

```
Server *server = malloc (sizeof (Server));
```

which actually allocates some memory for you to use.

Think of the difference as follows:

```
Server *server;              |  Server *server = malloc (sizeof (Server));
       +----------+          |         +---------+     +-----------+
server | ???????? | --> ???  |  server | pointer | --> | structure |
       +----------+          |         +---------+     +-----------+
```

Comment: But isn't the call following that doing so?
memset(server, 0, sizeof(Server));

Comment: No, that's almost certainly the one causing the error. All `memset` does is to fill memory with a given value, you still have to have a valid addressable memory block - you're effectively passing it a random address to start filling from. When I use the malloc, I get back `Result: 0` from the program.

Comment: Thanks, that absolutely did it! Helped me understand the pointer thing just a bit more, too.

Comment: +1, excellent post, especially after the edits. Nice ASCII art.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
// Set up socket stuff
Server *server; // Set up the server
memset(server, 0, sizeof(Server));
```

This is incorrect. Here, you're asking `memset` to zero out the memory pointed to by `server`. The call to `memset` is correct, it's the pointer `server` that isn't. This line:

```
Server *server;
```

Allocates memory for and gives you a pointer, but it does not allocate any memory for the pointed-to object, and it does not give the pointer an initial value. Thus, after this line, the pointer is just pointing to some random spot in memory. (It's using whatever was left over in RAM, probably) We haven't assigned it a valid value yet, so it's not valid to pass it to `memset`.

Now, we need to give it a valid value. You could either:

1) Allocate a `Server` on the stack, by just saying:

```
Server server;
memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
```

2) Allocate a `Server` dynamically, using `malloc`:

```
Server *server = malloc(sizeof(*server));
// Check for NULL, which means malloc failed.
```

(Also, note the use of `sizeof` - using the variable name instead of the type will allow the `sizeof` to adjust if you ever change the type of the variable.)

You might want to find and review a basic tutorial on pointers. This is a pretty classic mistake of someone who's just encounted pointers for the first time, so, don't feel too bad.

Comment: Much appreciated, Thanatos. I actually just got done learning this in school, but the example there was ready made. I learn best by making my own mistakes. I totally forgot about malloc. I had memset on the mind from looking through other posts for an answer first. I'd upvote this if I could. Thank you kindly for the warm welcome, too.